Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve host firestore.googleapis.com, cause=java.lang.RuntimeException:
I have the application where it download the data and goes in offline mode then i want to check that all the data is store local or not ... which is playling on app so for that i disconnect the internet
This issue arises when I disconnect the WiFi. I think this issue is related to internet connectivity.
I try when i connect the internet then the media playing again when i disconnect the internet is stuck in splash screen and giving the exception Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve host firestore.googleapis.com, cause=java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "firestore.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname

check your internet connection.
